# file_get_contents good way to handle errors

Tags: php, html

I am trying to error handle the file_get_contents method so even if the user enters an incorrect website it will echo an error message rather then the unprofessional

> Warning: file_get_contents(sidiowdiowjdiso): failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 6

I thought if i make a try and catch it will be able to catch the error but that did not work.

```
try  
{  
$json = file_get_contents("sidiowdiowjdiso", true); //getting the file content
}  
catch (Exception $e)  
{  
 throw new Exception( 'Something really gone wrong', 0, $e);  
}
```

Comment: If you want to read URLs you should at very least validate that they look like URLs first, otherwise people could read files on your server.  A better alternative might be using CURL

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try cURL with [curl_error](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) instead of file_get_contents:

```
<?php
// Create a curl handle to a non-existing location
$ch = curl_init('http://404.php.net/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$json = '';
if( ($json = curl_exec($ch) ) === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else
{
    echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
}

// Close handle
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: Down-voted as this is not an answer to the OP's question regarding use of file_get_contents() - offering an alternative is not a real solution. The OP asked for how to handle the errors and warnings from file_get_contents() not how to do it a completely different way. Please note that cURL is not a drop-in replacement for PHP's file_get_contents() and anyone making the move will have to severely refactor their code, hence why this is not an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 10):

`file_get_contents` do not throw an exception in error, instead it returns false, so you can check if the returned value is false:

```
$json = file_get_contents("sidiowdiowjdiso", true);
if ($json === false) {
    //There is an error opening the file
}
```

This way you still get the warning, if you want to remove it, you need to put an `@` in front of `file_get_contents`. (This is considered a bad practice)

```
$json = @file_get_contents("sidiowdiowjdiso", true);
```

Comment: It may be better to discuss [error_reporting()](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) than promote the use of `@`

Comment: Perhaps it is worth noting that while using the `@` prefix may prevent displaying the error message to users, if you are logging errors to files using a function assigned to `set_error_handler` then you will still see the warnings logged in the files, and if you haven't then they will be included in your web server logs.

Answer (score 5):

You could do any of the following:

Set a global error handler (that will handle WARNINGs as well), for all of your unhandled exceptions: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Or by checking the return value of the file_get_contents function (with the === operator, as it will return boolean false on failure), and then manage the error message accordingly, and disable the error reporting on the function by prepending a "@" like so:

```
$json = @file_get_contents("file", true);
if($json === false) {
// error handling
} else {
// do something with $json
}
```

Comment: when i tried this code it always read false even if the URL was valid

Answer (score 0):

As a solution to your problem please try executing following code snippet

```
 try  
{  
  $json = @file_get_contents("sidiowdiowjdiso", true); //getting the file content
  if($json==false)
  {
     throw new Exception( 'Something really gone wrong');  
  }
}  
catch (Exception $e)  
{  
  echo $e->getMessage();  
}
```

Comment: still get a warning when i executed your code

Comment: Now please try to execute the above code snippet

Comment: same result always returns false even if a valid url is entered such as www.google.com

Comment: Please specify url in following format http://www.google.com i.e along with http

Comment: @Hashey100: `www.google.com` is a valid _hostname_, not a full URL. A proper URL also requires the _protocol_ (`http://`, `https://`, etc). Without one, `file_get_contents()` assume `file://` and tries to retrieve a local file named `www.google.com` in its current directory.