# file_get_contents() handling error message

Tags: php

I have a working function to get external website speed.

```
$t = microtime( TRUE );
file_get_contents( "http://www.example.org" );
$t = microtime( TRUE ) - $t;
print "It took $t seconds!";
```

However, if the external url is down, it prints this;

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.example.org): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! 
HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error in /home/china/public_html/dene.php on line 47
It took 14.4556088448 seconds!
```

What is the corerct way, to print "Site down", instead of getting that error ?

Comment: Try cURL with curl_error instead of file_get_contents because file_get_contents do not throw an exception in error, instead it returns false, so you can check if the returned value is false
Check here Answer given by  @Andrey Volk  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16130818/file-get-contents-good-way-to-handle-errors#answer-16130898

Comment: in php 7.0 file_get_contents fail throws an exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check whether the call to `file_get_contents`was successful:

```
$t = microtime( TRUE );
@$content = file_get_contents( "http://www.example.org" );
if($content === FALSE) {
    print "Site down"; // or other problem
} else {
    $t = microtime( TRUE ) - $t;
    print "It took $t seconds!";
}
```

The `@` is there to suppress the warning. Also Note the `===`.